# Informações de uma tag específica

Tags: git

Estou procurando informações presentes nas tags de um repositório com o seguinte comando que me retorna as informações dependendo do parâmetro que eu passe na flag `--format`.

```
git tag --format="%(refname) %(taggerdate)"
```

A questão é que esse comando me retorna informações de todas as tags presentes, porém o que eu preciso é de uma tag específica.

Existe algum comando que eu passe como parâmetro o nome da tag e tenha como resposta as informações da mesma?

Ex: `git tag $nomeDaTag --format="%(taggerdate)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o comando `grep` após a saída do comando para filtrar pelo nome da branch. Veja um exemplo para filtrar pela branch de nome `v1.0.1`:

```
$ git tag --format="%(refname) %(taggerdate)" | grep v1.0.1
```

Ou, usando o `--list` do [próprio git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#git-tag---list), você também pode fazer este filtro:

```
$ git tag --format="%(refname) %(taggerdate)" --list 'v1.0.1'
```